Why can't the aldehydes tautomerize in the reaction of Aldehydes with PCl5 to form alkyl chlorides?
My teacher gave us this question where CH3CH=O (ethan-1-al) reacts with PCl5 to form geminal dichloride CH3CHCl2 (1,1-Dichloroethane).

CH3-CH=O + PCl5 → CH3-CHCl2 + POCl3 + HCl

He explained the mechanism as:
sample of PCl5 exists as a compound of two ions PCl4+ and PCl6- where, PCl4+ acts as a Nucleophile and accepts a lone pair from the double bonded oxygen (step-1). Then, in order to gain stability, the PCl6- releases a Cl- anion which then attacks the π* orbital of the C=O bond of the carbon bonded to the trivalent oxygen (step-2). Then, since the P=O bond is very stable, the oxygen donates a lone pair to phosphorus thus kicking out a Cl- ion which then gets bonded to the partially positive carbon (step-3).

But my question is that why can't the aldehyde tautomerize into an enol and then the lone pair of oxygen attacks the PCl4+? i.e. why can't ethan-1-al, in this case, tautomerize into ethen-1-ol and then react?
I tried out the mechanism after tautomerizing, and formed chloroethene as a product. I've attached it below:

CH3-CH=O + PCl5 → CH3=CHCl + POCl3 + HCl

Mechanism:

Now, my teacher formed 1,1-dichloroethane while I'm getting 1-chloroethene so could anyone please explain which mechanism is correct? and why?
Also, please do tell that in a general case, if a ketone or aldehyde is made to react with PCl5, will we consider the product formed after tautomerization as well?
Thank you

Maybe this is because ethanal is more stable than ethen-1-ol, so, 1,1-dichloroethane might be major product here.

Because keto-enol tautomerism greatly favors the keto form unless the enol form is stabilized (for example through resonance or hydrogen bonding).
